# Error creating cell with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I do an export from Java to xls, i use POI library.

My createCell Method:

```
private Cell createCell(Row ligne, int col, String value, CellStyle style, HSSFWorkbook classeur) {        
    //org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFOptimiser.optimiseCellStyles(classeur);
    CellStyle styleCell = classeur.createCellStyle();
    styleCell.cloneStyleFrom(style);
    return createCell(ligne, col, value, styleCell);
}


protected Cell createCell(Row ligne, int col, String value, CellStyle style) {
    Cell cell = createCell(ligne, col, value);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    return cell;
}
```

i call this methods in a For, i have this message error:

> Echec de l'export: The maximum number of cell styles was exceeded. You
>   can define up to 4000 styles in a .xls workbook

How to reuse my cell without having to recreate each iteration ?

Thx

Comment: Try to declare the `styleCell` object outside the method as global and use it inside the method.

Answer (score 15):

You can not re-use the same cell for multiple rows. Instead, apply same values to a newly created cell. But you can use the same style to multiple cells.

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workSheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
cellStyle.setWrapText(true);

for (int i = 0; i <= records.size(); i++) {
    // Create a new row
    Row row = workSheet.createRow((short) i);
    Cell cell001 = row.createCell(columnIndex);
    cell001.setCellValue("some value");
    cell001.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use,

```
newCellStyle = oldCell.getCellStyle();
newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
```

instead of,

`newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());`