# Apache POI to create multiple cell styles for same worksheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working to create multiple cell styles in a sheet that can be applied to different cells in the worksheet.

While having only one CellStyle the code was very smooth and fast, but after adding multiple CellStyles it seems to be slower.

Is there a better way to handle this (adding multiple cell styles in a worksheet)

Below is my working code:

```
public static String createReport(){

    try {

        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        String reportFile = "Report.xls";
        System.out.println("reportFile : "+reportFile);
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(reportFile);
        worksheet = workbook.createSheet("Report");

        cellStyle = worksheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        Font font = worksheet.getWorkbook().createFont();

        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);             
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);            
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);              
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);


        cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStyle.setRightBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);

        font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        font.setBold(true);
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
        cellStyle.setFont(font);




        //Create a cell style for Pass status
        cellStylePass = worksheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();

        cellStylePass.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);
        cellStylePass.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cellStylePass.setWrapText(true);
        cellStylePass.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellStylePass.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);             
        cellStylePass.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);            
        cellStylePass.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);              
        cellStylePass.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);


        cellStylePass.setBottomBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStylePass.setTopBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStylePass.setLeftBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStylePass.setRightBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);

        cellStylePass.setFont(font);


        /*********************FAIL************************/
        cellStyleFail = worksheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();

        cellStyleFail.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
        cellStyleFail.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cellStyleFail.setWrapText(true);
        cellStyleFail.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellStyleFail.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);             
        cellStyleFail.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);            
        cellStyleFail.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);              
        cellStyleFail.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);


        cellStyleFail.setBottomBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStyleFail.setTopBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStyleFail.setLeftBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        cellStyleFail.setRightBorderColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);

        cellStyleFail.setFont(font);



        //Create first Row
        Row row1 = worksheet.createRow(0);

        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 0, "S.No.",cellStyle); 
        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 1, "ScenarioName",cellStyle); 
        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 2, "Environment",cellStyle); 
        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 3, "STATUS",cellStyle); 
        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 4, "",cellStyle); 
        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 5, "",cellStyle); 

        worksheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,3,5));

        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 6, "Execution Time",cellStyle); 
        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 7, "",cellStyle); 
        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 8, "",cellStyle); 

        worksheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,6,8));

        CellUtil.createCell(row1, 9, "Comments",cellStyle); 


        //workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();

        //Create 2nd row
        //Write names of bank title
        Row row2 = worksheet.createRow(1);

        CellUtil.createCell(row2, 3, "TPB", cellStyle);
        CellUtil.createCell(row2, 4, "WFB", cellStyle);
        CellUtil.createCell(row2, 5, "BOI", cellStyle);
        CellUtil.createCell(row2, 6, "TPB", cellStyle);
        CellUtil.createCell(row2, 7, "WFB", cellStyle);
        CellUtil.createCell(row2, 8, "BOI", cellStyle);




    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Pass";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of with this could be the use of your createReport() method.  If you're only calling the method once then everything in your code looks good to me. If the method is called more than once you may want to pull the CellStyle definition out so they are created only once and then reused with each successive method call.

Side note: watch out for too many CellStyles being created.  Creating more than 4000 will cause java.lang.IllegalStateException

some more info below:

[Error creating cell with POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143596/error-creating-cell-with-poi)

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#createCellStyle()